# Call Multiple Methods on one Line?

Tags: java, methods

If I have a line like this in my program:

```
fireBalls.add(new Fireball(tileMap).setPosition(20, 20)); // set position is a method of the fireball class
```

How can I call multiple methods like that, on that same line?

I tried this:

```
fireBalls.add(new Fireball(tileMap).setPosition(20, 20).setLeft());
```

But the `setLeft()` method can't be put there, as it can't be called on a void type.
I can't have them on separate lines, as I don't know what index it would be in the fireBalls ArrayList.

Comment: Change the return type of `setPosition(int, int)` and `setLeft` to `Fireball`? You can just add a `return this;` as the last line of the method. Although, it would seem more wise to add more params to your constructor. Also, you can create the instance before you add it to the list or if you want to get the index after you add it to the `List`, you can just do `Fireball justAdded = fireBalls.get(fireBalls.size()-1));`

Comment: There is such a thing as trying to be too succinct, and perhaps this is one of those occurrences.

Comment: The best answer is to probably not do this at all.  Use multiple lines.  I'm no Java pro, but I can't imagine using multiple lines would effect performance in the slightest... but it'd certainly increase readability... which increases maintainability... which increases performance...

Comment: @nhgrif I can't use multiple lines, because I don't know the index of the Fireball that was added to the ArrayList.

Comment: @sparklyllama: that makes no sense -- you don't need to know the index. You just need to have a reference to the object, and you can easily do that by creating a local Fireball variable, setting it up, and then adding it to the ArrayList. For example, see code in my answer.

Comment: Fireball f = new Fireball(tileMap); f.setPosition(20,20); f.setLeft(); fireBalls.add(f);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to be too succinct and in the process possibly shooting yourself in the foot. You don't need to know the ArrayList index to set up the Fireball object that you're adding. You just need to have a reference to the object, and you can easily do that by creating a local Fireball variable, setting it up, and then adding it to the ArrayList.

Why not simply do:

```
Fireball fireball = new Fireball(tileMap);
fireball.setPosition(20, 20);
fireball.setLeft();
fireBalls.add(fireball);
```

Comment: This is a great alternative to what other people have be suggesting. Thank you for helping! +1

Comment: The accepted answer should be changed to this one in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

You can modify your `Fireball` methods, so they return an instance of that class (in other words `return this;`)

```
public Fireball setPosition(int x, int y) {
    ...
    return this;
}
```

With this, the call to

```
new Fireball(tileMap).setPosition(20, 20)
```

will return the recent created instance, so you can call `setLeft()` from that instance. 
You could implement this for `setLeft()` too.

```
public Fireball setLeft() {
    ...
    return this;
}
```

Comment: For reference purpose : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 4):

To do that, your `Fireball` class should follow [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern, which methods return the instance itself. So, you can can chain the method in a line.

For example method : [`java.lang.StringBuilder#append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

While I believe Hovercraft's answer is the best by far, an alternative solution might be to write a better constructor.

A constructor that takes a `tileMap` (whatever this is), two `ints` for setting position, as well as a `boolean` or enum or something appropriate for whatever `setLeft()` does could be used here.

```
fireballs.add(new Fireball(tileMap, 20, 20, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make mathod chain like this :

```
 class a{ 

    static a obj= new a();

    static a show(){
       System.out.println("omg");
       return obj;
    }

    static a show2(){
        System.out.println("god");
        return obj;
    }

    void show3(){
       System.out.println("Research done");
   }
```

}

public class eg4{

```
public static void main (String hv[]){
     a obj2= new a();
     obj2.show().show2().show3();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use anonymous inner class like this

```
fireBalls.add(new Fireball(tileMap){{setPosition(20, 20);}});
```

or

```
fireBalls.add(new Fireball(tileMap){{
    setPosition(20, 20);
    setLeft();
}});
```

I use it sometimes in tests. Not the most readable way.

[java](/questions/tagged/java)